# How to write minimum linq query with many-to-many table involved?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

`Product` and `ProductCategory` tables are "connected" via many-to-many table `ProductToCategory`.

For some product with some id(let's mark it as **product_1**) I need to get the next product of the same **category** as the **product_1**.

I wanted to do this with **one** query, so the following query does the work but the sql-profiler shows very HUGE query. Are there any suggestions how rewrite the query?

```
(from p in cxt.Products
 join c in cxt.ProductToCategories on p.Id equals c.ProductId
 where p.Id > id && c.CategoryId == (from p2 in cxt.Products
                                     join c2 in cxt.ProductToCategories on p.Id equals c.ProductId
                                     where p2.Id == id
                                     select c2.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()
 orderby p.Id
 select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please, post data sample because this seems a little ambigous: they are a m:n relation ship between product an categoy and you talk about 'next product of the same category' (same category means 1 category but this is a m:n then they are more than one category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I suppose that when is said

> I need to get the next product of the same category as the product_1.

what really means is

> I need to get the next product of the one of categories of product_1.

```
(from p in ctx.Products
join c in cts.ProductsToCategories on c.ProductId 
join c2 in cts.ProductsToCategories on c.CategoryId = c2.CategoryId 
join p2 in ctx.Products on c2.ProductId = p2.id
where 
  p2.Id == id &&
  p2 != p
orderby p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @aF. Thanks for improving grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a view in the database called NextProductInCategory and then have a simple linq query to retrieve what you want.